# Обособление слова "типа"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, семантика, вводные-слова, междометие

Скажите, нужно ли обособлять слово "типа", когда оно выступает как слово-паразит, указывающее на низкий уровень речевой культуры персонажа? Теоретически его ведь в таком случае можно заменить на "мол", "дескать", тогда обособление логично. Ведь на "как бы" или "вроде", которые не обособляются в таких случаях, по смыслу заменить не очень получается: неблагозвучно, и не говорят так. "Грамота.ру" на этот счёт даёт весьма пространное разъяснение, которое кажется неполным (см. [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_148)). Так каково правило с "типа" или это вариативно?

*Ну он такой, типа, иди отсюда. А я ему, типа, не пойду! Чё ещё он выдумал. Крутой, типа, понимаешь...*

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамма.ру" ответила, что *разговорное слово "типа" в приведенных и подобных примерах нужно выделить запятыми.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно. В этом случае "типа" выступает в роли междометия.
Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Да и слева сосед тоже не подарок, просто берет снег, сгребает в мою
> сторону ― и поехал, я же, типа, сейчас не на колесах, так переберусь
> через завалы.
> *(Сальников)*

> ― Что ж, я ей врать буду?
> ― А ты, типа, никогда не врешь! ― задрала
> нос Алиса.
> *(Каганов)*
>
> ― Вы не обращайте внимания! Она у нас, типа, придурочная! У нее папаша
> зэк, ― встряла Лена Мумрикова...
> *(Емец)*

Answer (score 2):

Сленговое слово-паразит (низкая культура речи, и всё такое) "типа" может использоваться **как частица и как междометие.**

**Частица** относится к конкретному слову и не обособляется, а обособленное **междометие** занимает позицию вводного слова.

Например: *У вас тут **типа** жарковато. **Типа**, он о нас ничего не слышал.*

Еще примеры: https://rrepetitor.ru/coma/tipa-zapyatye-stavyatsya-ili-net/